# Contacting multiple potential advisors, while already a PhD student. What is the etiquette?

Tags: advisor, etiquette, changing-fields

I am currently a PhD student in the US, and have an advisor, but I am in the process of changing my advisor and consequently my project and area of research. I was advised by the department to contact potential advisors, and because there are also critical, funding-related, administrative steps involved, I have to first find an advisor who gives me a funded PhD position. I know in a normal situation, e.g. if I was applying for the PhD program from another institution, it would make sense to contact multiple potential advisors and move forward with them in parallel up to some point, as it has been advised in response to [this](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/123816/is-it-ok-to-contact-multiple-potential-supervisors) and [this](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/102225/contacting-multiple-potential-supervisors-at-the-same-department) questions. But in my case:

1. I am already a PhD student, with an advisor and a project, and my position depends on funding both from the department and future advisors. I am changing my advisor.
2. This process should be done relatively quietly. My current advisor should not figure this out, although the DGS is aware and helpful. This is because of history of retaliation from my current advisor, which should be taken seriously since changing advisors might take some time or may not be possible at all.
3. Since my area of research will inevitably change, any work I do before changing advisors is mostly going to be a waste of time. I also have a hard deadline to complete the process by April so all advisors can figure out how many new students they want for the next year. So, I have to try to get this done as fast as possible.
4. I am changing research areas, and considering professors within the same department with somewhat different research areas. I do have the background to go in either direction, and interest-wise, I am equally interested in both.
5. I was admitted to the program mostly because my current advisor wanted to hire me. For other professors, I am like a new applicant, who is going to take a spot in their group. So, understandably, they are going to vet me and move with caution, probably starting with a collaboration. (This was my experience with my first attempt, which did not work out)

That is to say, I have a time constraint, that I cannot attempt a potential advisor and once they clarify they will not take me, I go for the next. On the other hand, I am not sure how I can justify for one potential advisor that I have been going through the same process with another and eventually this would be a complete waste of time for at least one of them.
Meanwhile, not being able to change my advisor at all is the second worst outcome, second to getting kicked out of the university.

What is the way to go about this? I have been considering

- Taking the risk and corresponding with multiple potential advisors in parallel, and somehow (not sure how?!) make it clear to them that there is a chance it will all fall through.
- Going full transparency and tell them I am going through this process with multiple faculty and why.
- Take the risk of wasting a lot of time and effort and just go one by one.

Any comments on these options? Is there a conventional etiquette for this situation? Any other suggestions?

Thank you in advance for your comments and suggestions!

Comment: What country and field? Standards may affect answers

Comment: Even though you feel your time constraint prohibits it, I think you'll get better responses from potential advisors by interacting with them one-at-a-time, rather than any sort of shot-gun approach. When I've been approaching in any sort of spammish approach, I usually delete the email, and don't think about it at all.

Comment: @AzorAhai-him- Country is the US, field is engineering, but my research area is theoretical (i.e. small research groups, but still students are funded by the professor)

Comment: @paulgarrett Is that true even for current PhD students? I thought since I'm already student in the department, I'll at least get to meet with the professor once

Comment: Yes, when you're already in the department, you can meet with faculty directly. But do not send bulk emails, and so on. Do not behave as though you will be "doing a favor" to whichever faculty person might take you on as advisee. Also, on the day you go to see Prof X, you should really have your mind oriented specifically toward them, their work, their projects... _NOT_ as generic-potential-advisor. Engage with the specifics...

Comment: Your DGS will have better advice for you than strangers on the Internet.  The way these things works is frequently specific to the field and even to your specific department.